# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 , image and html file

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, ftp

My background image doesnt load in the index.html and i get  Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 while im adding the background image in the styleIndex.css , and i try to add it directly into the html by putting  but it didn't work either , also i have and  pointing to menu.html , and when i click well the menu.html doesnt load and i get the same error.

[Files disposition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Dekf.png)

index.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="Viewport" content="width=device-width">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./CSS/styleIndex.css">
<title>Spicy Chicken</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="logo">
  <img src="./imgs/spicyChickenhdpi.png" alt="">
</div>
<div class="wraper">
<a href="./menu.html #anchor"><div class="button1">Notre Menu</div></a>

/* here is the refrence to menu.html */

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

styleIndex.css:

```
*{
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 }
 body{
 background-image: url("../imgs/index.jpeg");

 /* here is the image that won't load*/

 background-size: cover;
 -webkit-background-size:cover;
 -moz-background-size: cover;
 -o-background-size: cover;
  height: 100vh;
  position: center;
  }
  /* The rest of the code isn't related to the body */
```

The styleIndex.css is inside the CSS file as shown in the Image above.

Comment: I copied the exact same code and disposition to my machine, the picture loads, maybe something else is blocking it from loading.

Comment: yeah it works on my machine too , but when i try to load in the server it doesn't , it's a big pickle ,i have to put it on server as soon as possible cuz i have a deadline for after tommorow :/